# TypeInitializationException WinForms at startup

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I'm getting the exception mentioned in the title at the moment i start my app. It worked perfectly i added the system.media library played some sounds and i tried to play the Exclamation sound that's when it crashed for first time. I deleted all of the newly added library's and code with Ctrl + z but now it wont even run that's what i get :

http://prntscr.com/9v8qjo
this is the sound i played `System.Media.SystemSounds.Exclamation.Play();`

```
    private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Shuffle();
        UpdateStatistics(folds, playedHands, lostHands, wonHands);
    }

    public MainPoker()
    {
        turns.Add(PFturn);
        turns.Add(B1Fturn);
        turns.Add(B2Fturn);
        turns.Add(B3Fturn);
        turns.Add(B4Fturn);
        turns.Add(B5Fturn);
        KeyPress +=
            Form1_KeyPress;
        _settings.Height = 140;
        _settings.Width = 90;
        call = bb;
        MaximizeBox = false;
        MinimizeBox = false;
        Updates.Start();
        InitializeComponent();
        PickNextBlind();
        Timer.Interval = (1000);
        Timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        Updates.Interval = (100);
        Updates.Tick += Update_Tick;
        tbRaise.Text = (bb * 2).ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Please provide [MCVE] inline in the post as text.

Comment: I tried but i literally don't know what causes the problem. What should i post, the constructor ? I tried putting breakpoint in the constructor but it wont trigger neither where my variables are declared so there's some problem not with my code and as i said it worked perfectly until i added the library. The program breaks exactly at the line marked in the screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. The problem was in my Resources. I have a string there which is giving value to a static string in my program something broke the string in the resources which caused invalid location for my static string. I just created a new Form ran it as a startup project and fixed the strings in my resources from there.

Answer (score 0):

Go the Exception Settings and add a checkmark for `TypeInitializationException`.

Run the debugger again - by doing this, it should stop at the point the exception is occuring. There you might find your problem.

I think you're accessing any file in your `MainPoker` class because the message says `The path is not of a legal form`. Just a guess ...

Comment: It does nothing still crashes at the same line

Comment: so then, can you post the code which will be executed as soon as the `MainPoker` class is instantiated? This is the constructor code, the member variable initialization and - assuming that this is a form - the `Form_Load` event (might be overridden as  `OnLoad()`)

Comment: Updated my question with the form_load method and the constructor

Comment: Hm, there could be suspicious code in `Shuffle()`, `UpdateStatistics()`, `Updates.Start()` or `PickNextBlind()`. Maybe in `InitializeComponent()` but I don't think so cause this should be the designer generated code only.

Comment: It doesn't even reach the constructor at least my breakpoint there is not getting raised